# Python: How to Extend List with List using Slicing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, slice

Note:
python Extend will extend your given list with existing list at the end.

```
>>>a = [1,2,3]
>>>a.extend([4,5])
>>>[1,2,3,4,5]
```

How to do the same using slicing?

at 0th position, middle or somewhere else it works as expected,

```
>>>l = [2,4,6,8,10]
>>>l[:0] = [0, 1]
>>>l
>>>[0,1,2,4,6,8,10]
```

Even i have tried,

```
>>> l[len(l):] = [100]
>>> l
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 100]
>>>
```

Is there better way without using function like **len()**?

but at the end its insert before last value.

```
>>> l[-1:-1] = [100]
>>> l
[2, 4, 6, 8, 100, 10]
```

expected output,

```
>>>[2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 100]
```

I know using **extend() method** but i want to achieve using slicing at the end..

Comment: The extended slice must start after the last element. The imaginary element after the last element has a positive index of L (the length of the list), but it does not have a negative index. You cannot solve your problem without knowing the length of the list.

Comment: @DYZ yes got it... to extend at the end i should need length.. otherwise i can use without length..

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works, though it's not as succint:

```
l[len(l):] = [100]
```

Comment: I know this, is there better way? without using function like len()?

Comment: Even the docs have the same approach: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html `list.extend(iterable)
Extend the list by appending all the items from the iterable. Equivalent to a[len(a):] = iterable.` @SilentSpectator

Answer (score 3):

In short, not exactly, because of [how slices work](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations) (emphasis mine):

> The slice of s from *i* to *j* is defined as the sequence of items with index *k* such that `i <= k < j`. **If *i* or *j* is greater than `len(s)`, use `len(s)`**. If *i* is omitted or `None`, use `0`. If j is omitted or `None`, use `len(s)`. If *i* is greater than or equal to *j*, the slice is empty.

Nevertheless, note that `lists` actually have a maximum size, which we can find with `sys.maxsize`. If we use that as the start of the `slice`, in conjunction with the emphasised part above, we can actually do something that will work for all `lists`:

```
import sys

END = sys.MAXSIZE

a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5]

a[END:] = b
print(a)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Of course, practically speaking, just use `len(a)`.

Comment: this is informative.. and we can try using import sys; sys.maxsize

Comment: @SilentSpectator Yup, I checked the `six` docs and it is equal to `sys.maxsize`. I actually edited my answer right before your comment!

Answer (score 2):

Just use `+=` which isn't using slicing, but is one of the ways without using an inbuilt function like len

```
In [1]: a = [1,2,3]                                                                                                                                                               

In [2]: a += [4,5]                                                                                                                                                                

In [3]: a                                                                                                                                                                         
Out[3]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

To use slicing, the python docs already provide a solution, also noted in [Amadan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56123478/8591431) . https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

> list.extend(iterable) .
>   Extend the list by appending all the items from the iterable. Equivalent to a[len(a):] = iterable.

Comment: How is this using _slicing_?

Comment: this is concatenation bro.. its not slicing

Answer (score 1):

As per document shared by @Devesh,

[Data Strutures](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) it extend your list we need length of list.

so we can use built in function len() to do it in simple way.

otherwise we can use **sys.maxsize**

```
>>> l = [2,4,6,8,10]
>>> import sys
>>> l[sys.maxsize:] = [100, 200]
>>> l
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 100, 200]
>>>
```

**One more Solution,**

Seems little better,

```
>>> l = [2,4,6,8,10]
>>> l[-1:] = l[-1:]+[100, 200, 300]
>>> l
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 100, 200, 300]
>>>
```

this is another method i have tried using `[].reverse()` method.

```
>>> l = [2,4,6,8,10]
>>> l.reverse()
>>> l[:0] = [3,5,7][::-1]
>>> l
[7, 5, 3, 10, 8, 6, 4, 2]
>>> l.reverse()
>>> l
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 3, 5, 7]
>>>
```